# Reading Berkeley DB in subversion 1.7

Tags: svn, berkeley-db, fsfs

I have a legecy subversion database that uses the Berkeley DB for the format.  When I load the current Windows binaries (1.7.x) for Subversion, none of the distributions appear to support Berkeley DB out of the box.  So, since I don't have a copy of the earlier verion of Subversion, how can I retrieve the data?  I don't mind converting to FSFS, but I can't do the initial dump since Subversion isn't able to read it (error message "Failed to load module for FS type 'bdb'.").

Any suggestions on what I can download to retrive my data?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to find an older release of Subversion, or find a current build which does support BDB. Getting away from BDB is a wise move.

Try [1.6.x from CollabNet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/svn-other)

Comment: Downloaded 1.6.19 from CollabNet but still get the "Failed to load module for FS type 'bdb'."  I'll try to track one down, but not obvious from a web search.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to follow up, I found a version of 1.4.2 stored in an archive directory on our servers.  I was able to access the database using this version.